# bash: cd: /usr/share/sqliv: No such file or directory

Tags: python

when I install sqliv with sudo python2 setup.py -i,Suddenly broken network,

then I reinstall sqliv like this,but get error

[image]

the code can't work

```
sudo python2 setup.py -i
```

What shoud I do?

Comment: Ummm, ask the authors of whatever `sqliv` is to be more careful when they copy/paste code so their code doesn't produce misleading errors? The culprit is the line 117 of `setup.py` where it prints a wrong path and it happens because you have `sqliv` in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @zwer Yes,you are right.First command cd then cd /usr/bin ,then rm -r sqliv,I sloved it.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I had nothing in that directory that I couldn't recover, I'd "ls -ls" /usr/share/sqliv, and if it exists, I'd "sudo rm -rf /usr/share/sqliv" and try to do the install again.  I could easily be wrong, but my guess is that you have some funky directory permissions set on the directory itself or a key file under that directory, and once that is cleared up stuff will work okay afterwards.  I also wonder if it might not be possible that the directory "sqliv" might not contain some appended invisible characters, like spaces.  In this case, doing a "sudo rm -rf /usr/share/sqliv*" might be necessary.  Be careful when typing any rm commands with wildcards, especially as root.

Comment: ,Yes,I did sudo rm -rf /usr/share/sqliv.I sloved it with First command cd then cd /usr/bin ,then rm -r sqliv.Thank you for your advice.